# Is there a way like apache(php) server config "open_basedir " to tomcat?

Tags: php, tomcat, xampp

Using php server I can restrict program access to the path `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/google.com` by writing a config like this:

`php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/local/apache/htdocs/google.com`

Is there a similar method for tomcat to restrict program access based on filepath?

Comment: Improved grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the [Security Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/security-manager-howto.html) to allow reading specific files/directories only.